# Calculate $I=\int d^{n}q\frac{(q^2)^{a}}{(q^2+D)^b}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I want to evaluate this integral :

$I=\int d^{n}q\frac{(q^2)^{a}}{(q^2+D)^b}$

It is a n-dimensional multiple integral in cartesian coordinates where $q=\sqrt{\sum_{1}^{n}q_{i}^2}$ is the Euclidean norm and $D$ is a constant.

Observe that the integrand is spherically symmetric so it can be easily solved in spherical coordinates. So ,

$I=(\int_{0}^{\infty}dqq^{n-1}\frac{(q^2)^a}{(q^2+D)^b})(\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}^n}{\Gamma (n/2)})$

The factor $\frac{2\sqrt{\pi}^n}{\Gamma (n/2)}$ is the area of the n-1 dimensional sphere in n dimensions.

So , How do you calculate the remaining integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}dqq^{n-1}\frac{(q^2)^a}{(q^2+D)^b}$ ??

Comment: Hint: The beta function can be written $B(x,y)=\int_0^{+\infty} t^{x-1}(1+t)^{-(x+y)}\,dt$. Try to rewrite your integral in that form (after doing something like $t=q^2$) and identify $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about the beta function.